# Blender Unresponsive

Tags: bones, selection-tools, performance, optimization

I am starting on a animation and every time I click something it waits and  says at the top of the window "Blender (Not Responding)".

I know what it means but is there a way to stop it from doing this? Its very annoying having to wait 7 seconds to select a bone. I don't know what to do I have tried turning of grid and outline selected and it still is slow.

Also, I am on a gaming laptop with a I7 and a gtx 960 so there should be no problems like with old computers.

Comment: We can't help you with the available information. Is your scene too big or complex? Is your computer busy doing something else in the background? Also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68311/blender-2-78-with-windows-10-lags-when-interacting-with-the-ui

Comment: i don't think so. the scene is entirely made of empties. only the characters are actual models. also i only had internet and premiere open. i have closed both of them now and nothing is really helping.

Comment: i got it up to a fair speed thanks dude! that article said i needed to run it with my gpu and that fixed it. thanks!