# Blender suddenly very slow

Tags: interface

I was working on a simple project with a single model, a backdrop and lamps, and suddenly, Blender became really, really slow. I tried starting a new project, restarting the computer, even reinstalling Blender, but nothing seems to help. What could have happened and what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: I’m not sure but you may be having the same problem I and several other people have run up against in the last few days. I just uploaded my post [Blender running at a crawl after NVidia update](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/73818/599). Look it over and go to the Blender URL listed for more info. Sorry this is not a fix, but I have some tickets out and will update when I get some answers.

Comment: @Marijn Tulp,  Steve King has posted his solution here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73818/blender-running-at-a-crawl-after-nvidia-update ....

Answer (score 1):

I am doing a Udemy Blender training and there they advised to do a forced update of display drivers. This appeared to be the cause of my problem, because since I rolled back the driver update, it works perfectly again.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem.  I found this similar one [Blender 2.78 with Windows 10 lags when interacting with the UI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68311/blender-2-78-with-windows-10-lags-when-interacting-with-the-ui), which seems to indicate a problem with Windows 10, which I was running. But I found that the solution was to right click on the blender shortcut>Run with Graphics Processor>Integrated Graphics.  Mine immediately went back to running fast when I did this.