# Blender running at a crawl after NVidia update

Tags: gpu, performance

I can’t say exactly the NVidia update was the cause but several other people and I have experienced a problem with Blender slowing to a crawl in the last few days. If you are having this same problem and are running Windows 10 with a NVidia GPU go to this Blender URL for more info:
https://developer.blender.org/T50650
I got this auto update from NVidia 2/13/2017 which is when I started having the problem:
NVIDIA - Display - 12/29/2016 12:00:00 AM - 21.21.13.7654
Check your update history. On Windows 10 do this:
Select the Start  button, then select Settings  > Update & security  > Update History (in the right hand column near the top in blue).

Comment: Is this a question, or an answer for what to do if your blender is running at a crawl?

Comment: This is an attempt to find an answer. I know of a lot of people having what sounds like the same problem I am having. All of them say this has come up in the last few days, not months ago. I may not be great at blog etiquette, but I do know how to fix a problem and that is to get all people involved looking at the problem.

Comment: This is not a blog, answering your own questions is possible on this site though and we welcome the effort. However if this is for future reference then please edit your question and write it in the form of a question so it is easier to find by searching or future users, then provide the solution for your problem as an actual answer bellow.

Comment: Sorry. I’m not use to solving problems in this type environment, but you make a good point that I’ll adhere to in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem has been solved for at least myself and some other people. I and at least one other person sent a bug ticket to NVidia. NVidia stated the auto update I received was a generic Windows update and not one from NVidia. They recommended getting the appropriate driver form this URL: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us and follow the NVidia instruction for installing it. I did the Advanced install and clicked the button to erase all of the old drivers to prevent any conflicts. It worked great and I think my Blender is running faster. I also downloaded the HP driver for this card as NVidia recommends, but it was more than 2 years old. I’ll just keep it for a backup.
I hope this solves the problem for others.