# I am having very slow performance running Blender

Tags: interface, performance, windows, installation, system

I just installed Blender and I am having very slow performance,when I press any menu buttons it takes around 3 sec. to respond or show is this normal? Do I need to set up something additional or install a driver?
I have read the system requirements are looking fine,it shouldn't be that slow.

Thank you

P.S.

I am using:
Samsung RC530
Intel core i7 , 2.20GHz
GeForceGT 540M,
6GB RAM DDR3,
500 GB SSD Samsung,
Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68311/blender-2-78-with-windows-10-lags-when-interacting-with-the-ui and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73818/blender-running-at-a-crawl-after-nvidia-update

Comment: I had this problem recently, and it was resolved by updating my Nvidia drivers. Instantly things were back to normal.

Comment: I just reinstall the drivers of NVIDIA and its working fine,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your video drivers up to date since Blender's UI is run entirely through OpenGL. Just search for your graphics card (GPU) online. If you do not know what model of GPU you have, then try going to the GPU brand's website usually you can find which brand of GPU you have somewhere on your computer's case or the box it came in. The brand will usually have an easy way to find out what GPU you have and provide you with updates.