# Is there any way to optimize the performance of blender on my computer?

Tags: performance

Quite some time back I had blender on this very computer and it worked great. Recently, my hard drive crashed and I decided to switch to SSD. I reinstalled blender on my computer and ran it. Now blender always lags seconds behind. It seems like the interface lags a lot.

Basically, if I perform an action, that action won't appear to have done anything until I've performed another action. I'm sure you can see how this makes it virtually impossible to work with blender.

I've looked every where for a solution and have found none. If anyone has a solution, I'd love to hear it.

I'm using a Toshiba laptop running Windows 7, 64-bit.
I'm currently downloading a display driver update.

Graphics card is an Intel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender 2.78 with Windows 10 lags when interacting with the UI](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68311/blender-2-78-with-windows-10-lags-when-interacting-with-the-ui)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I took a look at this but I don't believe I can do the same thing on windows 7. If so I'm not sure how. @Denis

Comment: If you have Nvidia graphics card, open Nvidia settings panel and there you can change individual program settings

Comment: My graphics card is an Intel.

Comment: Have you reinstalled graphics drivers after OS reinstall?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yes.

Comment: Intel cards are known to cause trouble and yield poor performance. Try changing the *Window Draw Method* in the *User Preferences > System*, making sure you save settings and restart between changes.

Comment: Just tested every draw method available. No change whatsoever. @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: Found a new driver update and installed it. Blender now works great. Thanks for all the help!