# Playback Speed way slow

Tags: animation

I have a problem I just cant figure out. I have read other posts on here but none seem to fix my problem. I dont believe this is a computer processing problem (4.2 ghz cpu, 64g ram, GTX 980 ti) I cannot get my playback speed of my animation over 2 fps. Its just a simple model with no background. I have tried other suggestions in post I have found but none seem to change anything, it still runs at 2 fps. Does anyone have any suggestions? Any thoughts?

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68311/blender-2-78-with-windows-10-lags-when-interacting-with-the-ui Are your drivers up to date? Is your computer busy doing something else? It is probably a good idea to also state your operating system. How are you playing said animation? can we get some screenshots?

Comment: My drivers are up to date. I am using Win 10. My system is not being taxed at all, when trying to run animation. I have my model in the 3d Ortho solid. Changing to wireframe has no affect. All the other posts I have seen on here about changing settings has no affect. It still just clips along at the same rate. You would think Blender would have a way to speed up and slow down the animation (like Spriter has a framerate speed). I am just completely stumped here. Any input would be welcome.

Comment: Now you got me confused. Are you saying playback is slow as in caused by bad performance and system playback issues, or do you mean that playback is smooth but your animation is playing slower then expected as in slow-motion effects?

Comment: I'm sorry. I will tell you exactly what I am doing. I have created a model (model and rig). I have never done any animating in Blender, so I am following a tutorial on Pluralsight. I am adding keyframes and hitting the play button on the timeline. The animation plays in slow motion at only 2 fps. If I click on Render / OpenGL Render Animation. I still get the slow motion. I have the Framerate set on 24 fps. I can use the left and right arrows and go through my animation faster, but when I click play it plays so very slow. Exercise files (tutorial) play right.

Comment: Well that sounds like you placed your keyframes with the wrong timing. Its hard to tell without looking at your scene or seeing screenshots of what you are doing. Please edit your question and provide all relevant details, some images may help, and if possible please provide a as **simplified file** as [possible reproducing the problem](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: OK, I was simplifying the project and discovered something. If I remove the model and just animate the bones, it play at the correct speed. But with the model displayed it slows back down. So its something to do with my model. Thing is its not even taxing my system. The cpu is not even heating up. There is plenty of resources for Blender to pull on to play this model. I truly don't understand.

Comment: Finally figured it out. Thank you for all your input. It was a modifier I had on the model that was not applied. Once I applied that modifier. It started working.