# New install of Blender unbearably slow UI - any suggestions?

Tags: installation

I'm a new user installing Blender 2.78c on a laptop with an i7, lots of RAM and rather basic GE Force 650M graphics. I used the installer.

As I move between the menus such as 'File', it takes a full second to open. Similarly running down the list of menu items has a lag of 1-2 seconds. The very first time I ran, I was able to pull up the User Preferences menu  but now, on subsequent runs, I can't seem to get any menu item to do anything.

I've uninstalled and re-installed with exactly the same result. I've looked at other similar questions and tried changing to use the integrated graphics with no change.

Does anyone have an idea as to what the problem might be?

Thanks.

Note: The solution given in [this issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68311/blender-2-78-with-windows-10-lags-when-interacting-with-the-ui) with very similar symptoms does not work in this case. In addition a I tried constraining the system to only use the integrated graphics but it did not help.

Comment: Have a look at background processes, CPU utilization, and Graphics utilization.  Blender does not run slowly by nature.  My Core I3 2.0Ghz laptop runs the UI very quickly.  I'm assuming you're experiencing this with the default scene as soon as you load Blender?  The only time I experience lag is when I'm actively rendering on the GPU. Also, what OS?

Comment: This is Windows 10. I don't see any processes using anything excessive. CPU is 1-4%, GPU 0%.

Comment: Do you have lag with any other programs?  What is CPU utilization while Blender is running?  I'm sorry, I've never experienced anything like that and I've had Blender installed on four different computers all with different architectures.

Comment: Everything else is running just fine. CPU is 1 to 4% with Blender running.

Comment: Try uninstalling Blender 2.78 and deleting C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation folder and download the 2.79 test build from here: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79  It doesn't require installation, just run the executable from the directory.

Comment: Uninstalled. There was no "Blender Foundation" folder to delete.  Ran test build - same issue.  Still no "Blender Foundation" folder after reinstall.  I appreciate all your suggestions - thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help you.  Without being at the computer, it's hard to tell.  One last thing could your anti-virus software be treating it like something malicious?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender 2.78 with Windows 10 lags when interacting with the UI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68311/blender-2-78-with-windows-10-lags-when-interacting-with-the-ui)

Comment: I had seen that post but the solution posted there does not work in this case.  It seems like this is different, but may well be related.

Comment: - Are you using the x64 version?
- Are you running a lot of background processes?
- Are your gpu and cpu drivers up to date? (OpenGL drivers could be out of date).
- Have you tried run the executable, ie not the installed version?
- Run a virus/malware scan?
- Try different versions from graphicall.org If that doesn't work more extreme options would be to try reinstalling windows or dual booting a linux build.