# Workstation becomes unstable during Cycles render with Cuda NVidia GTX 970 enabled or disabled

Tags: rendering

I have a workstation with two GTX 970 boards. Using Blender 2.78c, regardless of the settings under File | User Preferences:

No Cuda
Use one GTX 970
Use two GTX 970s

the workstation immediately becomes unstable as soon as I try a Cycles render. This either makes the workstation unusably slow or blue screens altogether.

Are there alternatives to Cycles that work with CUDA?

**System Info:**

```
Windows 10 Pro
Version 1607
OS Build 14393.1358

Processor:   Intel Core i7-6700K @ 4GHz
System Type: 64-bit OS, x64 based processor
Installed RAM: 32 GB
```

Two NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970
Driver NVIDIA 2017-Feb-23 21.21.13.7878

**Updates**

- The NVIDIA Drive has been updated to 2017-Jun-27 version 22.21.13.8476
- The resource monitor shows CPUs at 100% as soon as a render in Cycles is initiated. (Even with both GTX 970s selected). Should the use of GTX 970s reduce the burden on the CPUs?
- I was able to close Blender 2.78c during one test and saw CPU usage immediately drop when Blender was closed.
- A complete hard shutdown is required after trying a Cycles render.

Comment: Same setup, works flawless. What OS? Latest drivers? Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7486/31447

Comment: Added system info to question.

Comment: Try to update your drivers. February is outdated, obviously. Also windows 10 has some serious issues: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68311/blender-2-78-with-windows-10-lags-when-interacting-with-the-ui/68583

Comment: February 2017 is the latest version recommended by Windows 10.

Comment: @DougKimzey If you are serious about your computer performance and overall health don't trust "Windows 10 recommendations". I'm pretty sure there are more up to date drivers from the source they should be downloaded from: [NVidias official site](http://www.nvidia.com/page/home.html) And avoid installing drivers (especially critical ones like graphics) from Windows update.

Comment: Also make sure your scene is not too big or complex for your hardware and available memory. Slowness and unresponsiveness is highly probable and totally expected while rendering, especially with bigger tile sizes and the closer you get to your memory limits

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that issues like this are usually due to drivers or hardware (ex, cooling) rather than Cycles. It is highly likely that any other CUDA-based renderer would exhibit the same issues.

Comment: Some additional notes - the scene is a very simple tutorial file from a PluralSight course. If you let Windows tell you what the proper drivers are, it will install the Feb 2017 driver. If you go to NVidias site (as recommended by Duarte) you can install a driver from June 2017.  I will be taking the course today (I hope) and will post notes on if it works on not.

Comment: An update - installed the 27-Jun-2017 drivers for NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970.  Still encounter instability as soon as a render is initiated with Blender Cycles. This occurs regardless of the Cycles Compute Device setting in User Preferences (even if "None" is selected).  Tried a run involving CUDA on the same machine in Wolfram Mathematica.  No problems at all.

Comment: One additional note - the scene is fairly simple.  It is the Blender Tutorial file from the PluralSight course: "Introduction to Materials in Blender".

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to digital tutors as well as my OS is Win7. However, might be a scene-file issue so I'd probably test with official benchmark scenes: https://code.blender.org/2016/02/new-cycles-benchmark/ instead. If you are able to reproduce the issue, consider to report a bug: https://developer.blender.org/ @DougKimzey

Comment: I will check the benchmark scenes as well as BIOS settings and post findings.