# Blender very slow after upgrading to windows 10

Tags: gpu, performance, windows, hardware, compatibility

So I recently did an upgrade on my old laptop. Its a very weak laptop with a ATI Mobility Radeon 3400 but blender always ran pretty well on it. Now after upgrading to windows 10 blender first said that It Can't detect 3d hardware accelerated drivers. So I got OpenGL 64x and put it in my blender direction. Now blender openend. But it is unusable slow. every input takes multiple seconds to react and even a simple thing as a swipe with the mouse is running in like 3fps (without anything in the scene)
Is there any way to fix that? I dont want to go back to windows 7 only because of blender but I also cant miss it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender 2.78 with Windows 10 lags when interacting with the UI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68311/blender-2-78-with-windows-10-lags-when-interacting-with-the-ui)

Comment: Putting OpenGL dll in the Blender's direction is only testing way to diagnose the problem with drivers, it is not and should not be used as permanent solution. Blender should find system drivers to work, the fact that Blender opened once you put OpenGL dll into its folder tells that your problem is in OpenGL drivers in the system