# Blender viewport is extremely slow (very low FPS)

Tags: 3d-view

I used to get 40 - 60 FPS in the viewport, now the viewport is completely frozen and moves with a 5 to 10 second delay. I have Intel HD graphics, Windows 10 and an i5 processor.

When I load up the default scene with the cube I get 70 FPS. I used to get 20 FPS with 400,000 vertices before. Now my current scene comprises of 250,000 vertices, but Blender is frozen 95% of the time.

I tried:

- Re-installing blender
- Doing a factory reset
- Change drawing modes

Is this a lost cause, or is there any way to fix/improve Blender? I really wanted to complete my first render without having to spend a load of money on a new PC.

Comment: Likely a video driver issue. Have you recently updated drivers or applied any updates? Or possibly related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68583/29586

Comment: @RichSedman No, I updated my drivers a while ago and they're still up to date now.

Comment: Windows 10 tends to update itself everything it thinks you need. So twice make sure to check driver version for the video card. In case of when something worked and suddenly doesn't the most possible reason are drivers like something that could be installed and affecting multiple programs

Comment: Can you try running in fullscreen mode? It might help avoid the slowdown.

Comment: @MikePan It was equally slow in fullscreen mode